What are the different .tff files given by Google fonts that differ only by <number>-pt?
Curious about the way fonts worked before web/variable fonts. I'm building a web page's CSS, following a video course. I downloaded the Inter font from fonts.google.com, and the download included multiple sizes for each style such as:
Inter_18pt-Regular.ttf
Inter_24pt-Regular.ttf
Inter_28pt-Regular.ttf

Why does it include multiple sizes? I guess if I use font size 20pt on my page it will scale whichever font I pick up or down to the target size. Should I pick the font file that's closest to the desired size? Or are these intended to be used together somehow?
I'm actually not using these files. I'm using the "embed" button to grab the fonts from Google's CDN, but I'm curious about these static files in the download.

These three file names represent three different optical sizes of the font Inter Regular. Here is an excerpt from Google’s explanation of the concept of optical size:

Optical sizes in a variable font are different versions of a typeface
optimized for use at singular specific sizes, such as 14 pt or 144 pt.
Small (or body) optical sizes tend to have less stroke contrast, more
open and wider spacing, and a taller x-height than those of their
large (or display) counterparts.

In the case of Inter Regular, the only difference seems to be the letter spacing.

You asked:

Should I pick the font file that’s closest to the desired size? Or are these intended to be used together somehow?

Yes, I imagine that you’d choose the font closest to the desired size. That would give you the appearance intended by the font designer. But at the end of the day the three optical sizes are available and you can decide whether to use one of them or a combination. It would only be really picky designers who would notice the difference.

Plus 1 - Thanks for taking the time to make the picture.

Note that, ironically, you don't actually want the size "closest to" your desired size, you either want that exact size (which might mean more than one font because headings etc have larger text size, thankfully CSS lets you define different source url() for different sizes) or a value that can "reasonably cleanly" be scaled to that size. So if you're targeting the standard 16px/12pt browser font size, you're more likely to want to use the 24pt version than the 18pt version, for example, as there will be fewer scaling artifacts.

In addition to Brett Donald's answer and referring to your question

Curious about the way fonts worked before web/variable fonts.

Simplified size variations (pre-variable font era)
Before Variable Fonts we also had size-related variations in advanced font-families like these mostly provided in 3 steps:

"caption" – made for small text sizes providing a decreased thin-to-thick line contrast, an increased x-height as well as an increased intrinsic "tracking" (letter-spacing) resulting in more "robust" printing results
regular styles
"display" – large font sizes like headlines

Frankly, you probably don't need more than 3 optical sizes to prevent an overkill of variations – albeit this is obsolete if you're loading a seamlessly interpolatable Variable font.
The differences are more pronounced when using serif fonts:
In a nutshell: In the days of metal typesetting, punch cutters optimised their type design for each font size to prevent the ink from bleeding too much (making the text bolder than desired or even unreadable) or breaking up completely due to too thin strokes (e.g. the thin line of an "e" stroke may simply disappear, making it resemble a "c").
Here's a modern interpretation of a "Bodoni" – the "Bodoni Moda"
The so called/categorized "Didone"  fonts (See also this nice article "Didone or Modern fonts" and about the Vox font classifications system ) have a stark contrast between vertical stems and horizontal hairlines.


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bodoni Moda';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400 900;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/bodonimoda/v25/aFTQ7PxzY382XsXX63LUYJSKSKg.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body {
  font-family: 'Bodoni Moda';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-variation-settings: 'opsz' 6;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fnt-siz-4{
  font-size: 4em;
}

.opt-caption {
  font-variation-settings: 'opsz' 6;
}

.opt-text {
  font-variation-settings: 'opsz' 12;
}

.opt-display {
  font-variation-settings: 'opsz' 96;
}
<!--
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bodoni+Moda:ital,opsz,wght@0,6..96,400..900;1,6..96,400..900" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<p>x-height/weight comparisons</p>
<h1 class="fnt-siz-4"><span class="opt-caption">Hxg</span><span class="opt-text">Hxg</span><span class="opt-display">Hxg</span></h1>


<h1 class="opt-caption">The Divine Comedy</h1>
<h1 class="opt-text">The Divine Comedy</h1>
<h1 class="opt-display">The Divine Comedy</h1>



<p class="opt-caption">When half way through the journey of our life I found that I was in a gloomy wood, because the path which led aright was lost. And ah, how hard it is to say just what this wild and rough and stubborn woodland was, the very thought of which renews my fear!
  So bitter ’t is, that death is little worse; but of the good to treat which there I found, I ’ll speak of what I else discovered there.</p>

<p class="opt-text">When half way through the journey of our life I found that I was in a gloomy wood, because the path which led aright was lost. And ah, how hard it is to say just what this wild and rough and stubborn woodland was, the very thought of which renews my fear!
  So bitter ’t is, that death is little worse; but of the good to treat which there I found, I ’ll speak of what I else discovered there.</p>

<p class="opt-display">When half way through the journey of our life I found that I was in a gloomy wood, because the path which led aright was lost. And ah, how hard it is to say just what this wild and rough and stubborn woodland was, the very thought of which renews my fear!
  So bitter ’t is, that death is little worse; but of the good to treat which there I found, I ’ll speak of what I else discovered there.</p>



"Optical" sizes
As you can see the higher optical-size values result in significantly thinner hairlines lines e.g in the horizontal serifs. In this case there is barely no x-height change. Maybe because the designer opted for a more authentic interpretation of the original? I don't know.
All in all, it's up to you, the designer, to choose the settings you want. So don't look at the numbers - always look at the font rendering. Similar to font weights, font A at font-weight:700 may be significantly thinner/less bold than font B at font-weight:600 - these values are arbitrary. therefore you should definitely not trust auto settings like font-optical-sizing: auto – what is this supposed to do? Why should it provide the "automagically" best result?
The term "optical size" tends to be a bit of a mystery: if a font has larger x-heights ... it is in fact larger because the vast amount of text relies on lowercase letters - so it's not an "optical illusion", just a design decision about how to share the available space for visible text rendering. Usually, the "caption" sizes also have a wider tracking - which can also be achieved by manual letter-spacing adjustments.
In case of the "Inter": the optical axes variations in a sans-serif font like the "Inter" font family can be considered slightly "gimmicky" as we don't really have significant "contrast" changes – they usually work fine even in small font-sizes where not providing significantly finer details in the "display" grades.
